# Does M2Crypto's public_decrypt(block, padarg) perform decryption or verfication?

Tags: c#, python, cryptography, rsa, m2crypto

I got some Python code that seems to use a public key  for decrypting  data. The data is probably encrypted using the corresponding private key. (I am not sure about it, because encryption with private key is normally called signing).

The Python code given below works fine if we have an appropriate public key file:

```
def decryptUsingPubKey(b64encData):

    dcdData = base64.b64decode(b64encData)
    block = dcdData[0:512]
    rsaObj = M2Crypto.RSA.load_pub_key(keyFile)
    padarg = M2Crypto.RSA.pkcs1_padding
    decData = rsaObj.public_decrypt(block, padarg)
```

What does the method `public_decrypt(block, padarg)` actually do? Does it decrypt some encrypted data, or does it just verify it?

And what is its alternate in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the M2Crypto library (but knowing a bit of cryptography), it looks like the `public_decrypt` function is just a wrapper around [OpenSSL's `RSA_public_decrypt` function](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_private_encrypt.html), a *low-level RSA operation*.

This is seldom useful per se, but it internally used in the signature verification operation.

As the decryption key is public, there is no way to use it for confidentiality, and to make a real signature scheme (for really short messages) out of it, you need some good padding scheme, too. For longer messages, you need to combine it with a hash function.

I would not recommend using it (and the corresponding `RSA_private_encrypt` function), and I don't see a reason for the M2Crypto library to expose it.

Comment: The functions are useful for this: http://sigpipe.macromates.com/2004/09/05/using-openssl-for-license-keys/. I think M2Crypto is the only python library that exposes them.